# What is the type of classes in Haxe?

Tags: class, dictionary, key, haxe

I'm trying to figure out what the general type of the key is for this map in Haxe:

```
var foo = [
    Foo => new Foo()
];
```

[This is me trying to figure it out](http://try.haxe.org/#0Af61) via `typeof` on http://try.haxe.org/, but I'm not able to make much sense of the output.

In my case, I can't infer the type like this and have to declare it ahead of time (`Map<ClassOrSomething, Foo>`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, the type of a class is `Class<T>` - for example, `Class<Foo>` or `Class<Dynamic>` would both work for your case.

However, [classes can't be used as map keys](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/1971) (old issue but to my knowledge this is still the case.) One alternative would be to use string class names for the keys. You can get the class name from the class with `Type.getClassName(Foo)`, and turn the string back into the class with `Type.resolveClass`. ([Haxe Type documentation](http://api.haxe.org/Type.html))

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  However using a key seems to function here: http://try.haxe.org/#6B8a0 . Perhaps they got around to implementing this?  Or maybe it just works on a js target.